# `std::pair` `second` has incomplete type with `unordered_map` tree

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, forward-declaration, std

I was reviewing some older code of mine and I saw the code using pointers to implement a tree of `Variant` objects. It is a tree because each `Variant` can contain an `unordered_map` of `Variant*`.

I looked at the code and wondered why isn't it just using values, a `std::vector<Variant>`, and `std::unordered_map<std::string, Variant>`, instead of `Variant*`.

So I went ahead and changed it. It seemed okay except one thing, I got [errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a3e9067ad4b9379):

> ```
> /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h:153:11: error: 'std::pair<_T1, _T2>::second' has incomplete type
>        _T2 second;                /// @c second is a copy of the second object
>            ^~~~~~ main.cpp:11:8: note: forward declaration of 'struct Variant'
>  struct Variant
>         ^~~~~~~
> ```

So I figured I could trick the compiler into delaying the need to know that type, which [didn't work either](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62a10804a01e49aa).

### <s>Working</s> Not Working! (*[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)*)

*I thought this worked earlier but it actually doesn't, I forgot `::type` on the `using HideMap...`*

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

template<typename K, typename V>
struct HideMap
{
    using type = std::unordered_map<K, V>;
};

struct Variant
{
    using array_container = std::vector<Variant>;

    // Does not work either
    using object_container = typename HideMap<std::string, Variant>::type;

    // Fails
    //using object_container = std::unordered_map<std::string, Variant>;

private:
    union Union
    {
        std::int64_t vint;
        array_container varr;
        object_container vobj;

        // These are required when there are union
        // members that need construct/destruct
        Union() {}
        ~Union() {}
    };

    Union data;
    bool weak;
};

int main()
{
    Variant v;
    std::cout << "Works" << std::endl;
}
```

So, my question is, why does it work okay for `vector` and not `unordered_map`?

If the problem is the inability to use incomplete types, is there a way to delay the instantiation of the `unordered_map`? I really don't want every object property to be a separate `new` allocation.

Comment: `HideMap` doesn't do what you seem to think it does.

Comment: @T.C. How do you know what I think it does? It causes two-phase lookup right?

Comment: @T.C are you referring to HideMap not actually being in itself an unordered map?

Comment: Oh! I forgot ::type!

Comment: @perencia Thanks, I changed the question.

Comment: Std collections require complete types. Vector implementations often permit more latitude than is mandated because it follows from the details of the implementation.

Comment: I tried to use partial specialization after `Variant`, to attempt to make it instantiate the map after the `Variant` type is complete, but that did not work either.

Comment: Probably duplicate of [c++ - How to have an unordered_map where the value type is the class it's in? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089388/how-to-have-an-unordered-map-where-the-value-type-is-the-class-its-in) .

Answer (score 1):

This uses placement new to defer the initialization of the `Union` to the constructor where `Variant` is a complete type. You need to `reinterpret_cast` everywhere you need to use the `Union`. I made an effort to not have any strict-alignment violations.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

struct Variant {
    Variant();
    ~Variant();

    private:
    std::aligned_union<0, std::vector<Variant>,
                         std::unordered_map<std::string, void *>,
                         std::int64_t>::type data;
};

namespace Variant_detail {
    using array_container = std::vector<Variant>;
    using object_container = std::unordered_map<std::string, Variant>;

    union Union {
        std::int64_t vint;
        array_container varr;
        object_container vobj;

        // These are required when there are union
        // members that need construct/destruct
        Union() {}
        ~Union() {}
    };
}

Variant::Variant() {
    //make sure that std::unordered_map<std::string, Variant> is not too large
    static_assert(sizeof(std::unordered_map<std::string, Variant>) <=
                      sizeof data, "Variant map too big");
    static_assert(alignof(std::unordered_map<std::string, Variant>) <=
                      alignof(decltype(data)), "Variant map has too high alignment");
    auto &my_union = *new (&data) Variant_detail::Union;
    my_union.vint = 42;
}

Variant::~Variant() {
    reinterpret_cast<Variant_detail::Union &>(data).~Union();
}

int main() {
    Variant v;
    std::cout << "Works" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: C++14 is okay, I should have tagged it c++14, I'll update tags.

Comment: @nwp Thanks! Is it even possible for the `static_assert` to fail now? cc @T.C.

Comment: What about that `void*` though? Where does that memory come from? `new` defeats the purpose. Should I change the implementation so the items in the map refer to some Variant objects held in a vector, and the map just indexes it?

Comment: @doug65536 In theory `std::unordered_map` could specialize on `void *` or on `sizeof(T)` of the actual type and be bigger/smaller or require different alignments. In practice I would not expect that to ever happen, but the `static_assert`s don't cost much, so I would leave them in. The `void *` is just some type so `unordered_map` compiles, there is no memory behind it.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that the vector should probably be a deque, so iterators won't invalidate, and an "object" should be an `unordered_map <reference_wrapper<Variant>, reference_wrapper<Variant>>` pointing into the deque

Comment: I feel that this answer is full of undefined behavior.