# How might one fix evp_cipher_ctx and std::pair<t1,t2>::second incomplete type errors?

Tags: openssl, std-pair, evp-cipher

I have been receiving the following compilation errors when running the following docker command in the picco, [an MPC compiler](https://github.com/PICCO-Team/picco), directory and after cloning the MPC-SoK/frameworks [github repo](https://github.com/MPC-SoK/frameworks):

```
docker build -t picco .
```

- Forward declaration of 'struct evp_cipher_ctx'
- 'std::pair<_T1, _T2>::second' has incomplete type
- 'EVP_CIPHER_CTX en' has initializer but incomplete type

I have seen many related github and stack exchange tickets and posts pertaining to one or more of these specific errors and none have actually supplied workable solutions to them, such as:

- [EVP_CIPHER_CTX  stackanswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518843/error-field-ctx-has-incomplete-type-evp-cipher-ctx)
- [EVP_CIPHER_CTX  github ticket](https://github.com/dun/munge/issues/54)
- [std::pair related stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37223272/stdpair-second-has-incomplete-type-with-unordered-map-tree)

It seems that the first and third errors are due to updates in Openssl however I have tried running fresh Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 VMs with 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1.0, and 1.1.1 of openssl and on Mac OSX High Sierra with openssl 1.0.2, all with the same point of failure and all with the same three classes of errors.

I have also tried the solution of [here](https://www.wittnet.org/kb/kb/218) where I manually went in and changed the EVP_CIPHER_CTX variables to pointers and used their associated freeing function. This too, did not work.

I would like to know if anyone has seen and successfully fixed these errors before, and if so what they did, on what machine, and with which dependencies if possible?

Comment: Can you include the link to the GitHub repo that you cloned?

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek I have added the link to the repo.

Comment: Thanks, that helped -- see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the repository that you mentioned, the `Dockerfile` starts with the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
WORKDIR /root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  bison \
  flex \
  g++ \
  git \
  libgmp-dev \
  libssl-dev \
  make \
  python \
  vim
```

One of the packages installed is `libssl-dev`, which has no indication of the version. Now `ubuntu:latest` is the latest Ubuntu LTS, for which currently some `openssl 1.1` version is the standard. That breaks your build, as you had figured out already.

It looks like the only thing you need to change is the selection of the `libssl-dev` package in `Dockerfile`, you have to replace it with `libssl1.0-dev`. That will install a `1.0.2` version of OpenSSL, for which the code was written. I found the name of that `1.0` versioned openssl package on this [Ubuntu 18.04 openssl package information page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/openssl).

Comment: @RienierTorenbeek Thank you very much that worked like a charm! I am still surprised though, that the code did not compile when I had downgraded my fresh vm's version of openssl to 1.0.2. As I made sure to check that the version being used after the downgrade was indeed 1.0.2.

Comment: My pleasure. Do you mean that you ran the actual `install.sh` script to build the stuff inside your VM? Or do you mean that the `docker build -t picco .` command still failed?

Comment: @z.karl: OK. The docker command will not succeed unless you change `Dockerfile`, because the entire build happens inside the docker and whatever you do outside of that will not have a lot of effect. I do not know why running `install.sh` inside your VM might not work after downgrading OpenSSL -- that could be another question :-)