# Why can I have a circular reference with a std::map but not a std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, circular-reference

The following code compiles without complaint:

```
struct M
{
  std::map<std::string, M> m;
};
```

The following code, on the other hand, does not:

```
struct U
{
  std::unordered_map<std::string, U> u;
};
```

We get the following error (after stripping a bunch of template vomit):

```
In instantiation of ‘struct std::pair<std::string, U>’:

error: ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::Second’ has incomplete type
```

Okay, I can see how letting arbitrary types depend on themselves could lead to problems.  But how is it that we run into this error only with certain types and not others?  `std::map` has the same interface as `std::unordered_map`; in particular, it depends on `std::pair` as well.

It's not a matter of simply not running into the error conditions with a small amount of code.  I can do something like this and it compiles, runs, and produces the expected result.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  M m;

  m.m["m"] = M();

  std::cout << m.m.size() << std::endl;

}
```

In fact, I'm informed that the `U` actually compiles and runs on the Microsoft compiler, just not on gcc or clang.

What is going on here?

Comment: [How to have an unordered_map where the value type is the class it's in?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13089641/8411406) might help

Comment: @Thanks, that's much more directly relevant: there's a special exemption from the rules for the smart pointer types written into the standard.