# Allocator for type that allocates itself

Tags: c++, templates, allocator, incomplete-type, recursive-type

So I got this recursive variant that holds the types `std::vector` and `std::unordered_map` which again hold the type itself.

Now this should work according to the standard because:

1. `std::unordered_map` is basically a smart pointer holding only references and at the point of definition it will not need to know the size of the types.
2. self referential `std::vectors` were accepted into the standard as of [N4510](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4510.html) as mentioned in this other [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913578/how-can-i-declare-a-member-vector-of-the-same-class).

Here's what I have:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:5,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:5,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:5,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:5,startLineNumber:14),source:%27%23include+%3Cvariant%3E%0A%23include+%3Cunordered_map%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E+/*+allocator+*/%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+StringType,+typename+Allocator%3E%0Aclass+JSON%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+StringType+%3D+std::string,+typename+Allocator+%3D+std::allocator%3CJSON%3E%3E%0Aclass+JSON+:+public+std::variant%3Cstd::monostate,%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++std::unordered_map%3CStringType,+JSON%3CStringType,+Allocator%3E,+std::hash%3CJSON%3CStringType,+Allocator%3E%3E,+std::equal_to%3CStringType%3E,+Allocator%3E,%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++std::vector%3CJSON%3CStringType,+Allocator%3E,+Allocator%3E%3E%0A%7B+%7D%3B%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:46.597812879708385,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Os%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:38.949671772428886,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:61.050328227571114,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:53.402187120291615,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <variant>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory> /* allocator */

template <typename StringType, typename Allocator>
class JSON;

template <typename StringType = std::string, typename Allocator = std::allocator</* map and vector */>>
class JSON : public std::variant<std::monostate,
                        std::unordered_map<StringType, JSON<StringType, Allocator>, std::hash<JSON<StringType, Allocator>>, std::equal_to<StringType>, Allocator>,
                        std::vector<JSON<StringType, Allocator>, Allocator>>
{ };
```

The problem is indeed not the self-similarity of this class object, but its allocator. It would work if the allocator satisfies the *allocator-completeness-requirements*:

> An incomplete type T may be used when instantiating vector if the
> allocator satisfies the allocator-completeness-requirements
> (17.6.3.5.1). T shall be complete before any member of the resulting
> specialization of vector is referenced.

But I can't fulfill those as the type is not incomplete BUT a template template!

```
template <typename StringType = std::string,
    typename Allocator = std::allocator<JSON<StringType,
                            std::allocator<JSON<StringType,
                                std::allocator<JSON<StringType,
                                    ... >>>>>>>
```

Meaning, I can't really describe the type. What am I to do in this situation? Could I maybe help myself out with a custom allocator?

**Simplified**:

This works:

```
struct A {
    std::vector<A> subAs;
};
```

This doesn't:

```
template <typename Allocator>
struct A;

template <typename Allocator = std::allocator<A /* <-- unfortunately a template template parameter */>>
struct A {
    std::vector<A<Allocator>, Allocator> subAs;
};
```

But I wonder since the allocator is implicit in the first example, making it explicit should also work imho?

Comment: It sure looks like the answer is "don't use inheritence"

Answer (score 3):

`std::unordered_map`'s allocator doesn't actually allocate memory for `unordered_map::value_type` elements, but for an internal node structure. This is done by rebinding the allocator.

You can do similarly by accepting any allocator (here, `void` is used as a dummy) then rebinding it:

```cpp
template <typename Allocator = std::allocator<void>>
struct A {
private:
    using alloc_traits = typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::template rebind_traits<super_vector<Allocator>>;
    using allocator = typename alloc_traits::allocator_type;
public:
    std::vector<A<Allocator>, allocator> vec_;
};
```

That way you need an allocator for `A<std::allocator<void>>`, which is `std::allocator<A<std::allocator<void>>>` with no "cycle".

Applied to your JSON struct:

```cpp
template <typename StringType = std::string, typename Allocator = std::allocator<void>>
class JSON : public std::variant<std::monostate,
    std::unordered_map<StringType, JSON<StringType, Allocator>, std::hash<JSON<StringType, Allocator>>, std::equal_to<StringType>, typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::template rebind_alloc<std::pair<const StringType, JSON<StringType, Allocator>>>>,
    std::vector<JSON<StringType, Allocator>, typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::template rebind_alloc<JSON<StringType, Allocator>>>>
{ };
```

But note that `std::unordered_map` *does* needs to have a complete type as its mapped type when you instantiate the class. See here: [How to have an unordered_map where the value type is the class it's in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13089388). You will need to do something else (I believe boost's unordered_map supports incomplete types, and boost's recursive_variant does something to allow it to be used as a mapped type of a regular unordered_map)

Comment: Thank you! From the link you provided it appears as if all the major standard libraries now support self referential unordered maps (see @Fedor 's answer to OT) so that would be one less thing to worry about.